Strange rendering after upgrading to react-native 0.76 and expo sdk 52
I just upgraded my project to react-native 0.76.3 and expo sdk 52. After upgrading, I noticed that sometimes views do not seem to render correctly (see images). In fact, the bug happens all over the app which is why I was unable to find the problem so far. Typically, a reload fixes the bug. However, the bug appears not only in dev builds but also production builds.
Sometimes, an entire scrollview that should cover the complete page, appears in a tiny part of the screen at a seemingly random position.
If anyone knows why the views (or something else) are broken or if some configuration is incorrect please let me know. I am happy to provide more details in case someone has a concrete idea.
Thanks.
first and third message not displayed correctly
first and third image not displayed correctly
